# what is the genesis of the term - the clinical significance?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, significance, meta-analysis

The literature suggests that p-value represents "clinical" significance.
(p-value, is a number whose value can range from zero to one.)To me,p-value does not measure clinical significance.Further, p-value or alpha significance represents so-called statistical significance. To be correct,clinical significance can be described by validity-coefficient based on reliability measures of effect-size (e.g. r)in a dataset This measure seems to describe the "clinical" significance. The statistical significance is based on sampling(sample-size) theory and clinical significance invokes measurement(error) theory.The difference in overall conclusions about the average effect-size are unlikely to occur. Overall, I understand that clinical significance is ill-defined? What is learned community viewpoint?